# How can I limit Zebra TC520K touch computer scanner to only scan 9 digit barcodes?

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I have a problem when scanning barcodes with the Zebra TC520K touch computer barcode scanner. In my case, there are several barcodes printed close to each other. But it's only one of those barcodes that I am interested in scanning. The problem is that if I don't aim exactly the right way, the scanner scans the wrong barcodes next to the one I'm interested in scanning. The specific barcode I want to scan is a specific value format, the format is a value consisting of 9 digits (0-9). Some examples: "123456789" or "012301231". Is there a in-built feature, method or property in the Android Java EMDK I can use to filter this specific barcode I'm interested in? How can I do this?

I saw that there is an option for selecting different decoders, but I don't think that is specific enough to only target barcodes with a value of 9 digits.

Thanks!

## Update:

I tried setting the decoder `code128` to length 9 with both `length1` and `length2`. But the barcode scanner still scans all barcodes, no only the one with a 9 digit length. Here is how I initialize the scanner and sets the scanner config:

```
// Method to initialize and enable Scanner and its listeners
    public void initializeScanner() throws ScannerException {
        if (scanner == null) {
            // Get the Barcode Manager object
            barcodeManager = (BarcodeManager) this.emdkManager
                    .getInstance(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.BARCODE);
            // Get default scanner defined on the device
            scanner = barcodeManager.getDevice(BarcodeManager.DeviceIdentifier.DEFAULT);
            // Add data and status listeners
            scanner.addDataListener(this);
            scanner.addStatusListener(this);
            // Hard trigger. When this mode is set, the user has to manually
            // press the trigger on the device after issuing the read call.
            // scanner.triggerType = Scanner.TriggerType.HARD;
            scanner.triggerType = Scanner.TriggerType.SOFT_ALWAYS;

            // Enable the scanner
            scanner.enable();

            // Scan Mode set to Multi Barcode
            ScannerConfig sc = scanner.getConfig();
            sc.readerParams.readerSpecific.imagerSpecific.scanMode = ScannerConfig.ScanMode.SINGLE_BARCODE;
            sc.decoderParams.code128.length1 = 9;
            sc.decoderParams.code128.length2 = 9;
            sc.readerParams.readerSpecific.imagerSpecific.beamTimer = 0;
            sc.readerParams.readerSpecific.imagerSpecific.aimTimer = 0;
            scanner.setConfig(sc);

            // Starts an asynchronous Scan. The method will not turn ON the
            // scanner. It will, however, put the scanner in a state in which
            // the scanner can be turned ON either by pressing a hardware
            // trigger or can be turned ON automatically.
            try {

                    scanner.addDataListener(this);

                    // Scan Mode set to Multi Barcode
                    //ScannerConfig sc = scanner.getConfig();
                    sc.readerParams.readerSpecific.imagerSpecific.scanMode = ScannerConfig.ScanMode.SINGLE_BARCODE;
                    // Thread.sleep(100);
                    sc.decoderParams.code128.length1 = 9;
                    sc.decoderParams.code128.length2 = 9;
                    sc.readerParams.readerSpecific.imagerSpecific.beamTimer = 0;
                    sc.readerParams.readerSpecific.imagerSpecific.aimTimer = 0;
                    // Thread.sleep(100);
                    scanner.setConfig(sc);

                    // scanner.read();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Do I have to disable all the other decoders for this to work? Do I have to only enable the `code128` decoder or what's wrong?

Comment: Which scanner/imager on the device you are using for decode - rear camera or scanner with aiming light?

Comment: Is it possible to use the aiming function? [TC52X/TC57X SERIES TOUCH COMPUTER](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/spec-sheets/mobile-computers/handheld/tc52x-tc57x.html), [SE4720 AND SE4770 OEM ARRAY IMAGER SCAN ENGINES](https://www.zebra.com/gb/en/products/oem/oem-engines/oem-array-imager-scan-engines/se4720-se4770.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done on a per-symbolgy basis using the EMDK.  Under [decoder params](https://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/8-0/api/reference/com/symbol/emdk/barcode/ScannerConfig.DecoderParams.html), select the decoder, e.g. Code 128 and set [length 1](https://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/8-0/api/reference/com/symbol/emdk/barcode/ScannerConfig.DecoderParams.Code128.html#length1) and [length 2](https://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/8-0/api/reference/com/symbol/emdk/barcode/ScannerConfig.DecoderParams.Code128.html#length2) to the same value, in your case 9.

Comment: Hi, please check my update in the question. Thank you for your help. I tried it but didn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is you are not setting the decoders when the scanner is IDLE, please see https://github.com/ZebraDevs/EMDK-Android-Samples/blob/master/BarcodeSample1/app/src/main/java/com/symbol/barcodesample1/MainActivity.java#L195 as the scanner needs to be in a certain state when applying settings.  It is also possible the barcode is being scanned as a more permissive symbology such as I2of5 and you can call getLabelType() in your onData() to see which symbology was actually decoded.